# Updating React Component with Backbone View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backbone.js

I have a backbone view model that gets updated on user action (in a react component)... Problem is once the model gets updated the react view isnt updating. How do i fix that? Small code snippet below:

**Backbone**

```
onShowListView(data) {
    const newIsVisible = data.collection === this.collection ? !this.get('listview_visible') : false;
    this.set('listview_visible', newIsVisible);
    this.set('edit_mode', false);
  }
```

**React component**

```
function showHideList(data) {
  D.dispatch('SHOW_LISTVIEW', {
    collection: data.collection,
    isVisible: !data.get('list_visible'),
  });
}

export default class ListView extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a onClick={() => showOrHideList(this.props.viewModelData)}>
          Click me
        </a>
        {this.props.viewModelData.listview_visible} // Assume this is present
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ListView.propTypes = {
  // optionsList: arrayOf(string),
  viewModelData: shape({
    attributes: shape({
      can_edit: boolean,
      edit_mode: boolean,
      listview_visible: boolean,
    }),
    collection: shape({
      iconName: string,
      models: arrayOf(shape({
        cid: string,
        id: string,
        attributes: shape({
          name: string,
          row_count: number,
          topological_model_id: string,
        }),
        name: string.isRequired,
      })),
    }),
  }),
};
```

Comment: I'm really curious why you would ever use backbone and react together...

Comment: Am working on a BIG migration project... Eevrything is backbone currently... Moving everything to react would be a HUGE task for now... What am doing for now is moving all the views to react as step 1 :(